# Автозаполнение данных datagridview

Tags: c#, база-данных, datagridview

Есть БД с двумя столбцами "Children" и "Sum".

Нужна помощь с автозаполнением данных.

Если в столбце "Children" пишется 0, то в сумму = 10000. Если 1, сумма = 12000. Если 2 и больше, сумма = 14000.

Помогите написать условия для заполнения

```
     private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
           if (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value == "0")
           {
            dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = 10000;    
           }
    }
```

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: К гриду привязан (bind) какой-нибудь источник данных? Или данные напрямую в него заносятся?

Comment: На прямую в грид вводятся данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если внутри именно этого события, то

```csharp
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
       var isInt = int.TryParse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value, out int childrensCount);

       if (!isInt)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Ошибка, невозможно определить количесство детей");
           return;
       }

       if (childrensCount < 0)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Ошибка, количесство детей меньше нуля");
           return;
       }

       double money;

       switch (childrensCount)
       {
           case 0:
               money = 10000;
               break;

           case 1:
               money = 12000;
               break;

           default:
               money = 14000;
               break;
       }
       
       dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = money;
}
```

Comment: Не обязательно этим событием, через него был пробный вариант